# Choose as value based on a selection

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have this XML input i want to transform:

```
<Money>
  <Balance>
    <Type>
      <BalCode>FW</BalCode>
    </Type>
    <Amount Ccy="PHP">4.00</Amount>
    <CreditDebit>CRD</CreditDebit>
    <Date>2013-08-19</Date>
  </Balance>
  <Balance>
    <Type>
      <BalCode>OP</BalCode>
    </Type>
    <Amount Ccy="PHP">5.00</Amount>
    <CreditDebit>CRD</CreditDebit>
    <Date>2013-08-19</Date>
  </Balance>
  <Balance>
    <Type>
      <BalCode>CL</BalCode>
    </Type>
    <Amount Ccy="PHP">6.00</Amount>
    <CreditDebit>DBT</CreditDebit>
    <Date>2013-08-19</Date>
  </Balance>
</Money>
```

And I want to have something like this as my output:

```
<Balances>
  <BalanceDate>2013-08-19</BalanceDate> <!--From Closing Date-->
  <Opening Ccy="PHP">5.00</Opening>
  <Closing Ccy="PHP">6.00</Closing>
</Balances>
```

How can I achieve this using XSLT.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Balances>
            <BalanceDate><xsl:value-of select="Money/Balance[Type/BalCode='CL']/Date"/></BalanceDate>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Money/Balance[Type/BalCode='OP']/Amount"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Money/Balance[Type/BalCode='CL']/Amount"/>
        </Balances>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks, just what I needed :), by the way what if for example for Opening I can choose between 'OP' and 'FW' what do I do?